# What is the way to pass in navigation property values to URI using Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have my entity Element with navigation property Ingredient:

```
public class Element
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }        
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

API controller defined:

```
[HttpGet("elements", Name = "GetElement")]
public Element GetElement ([FromUri] Element element)
 {
  //<..>
 }
```

How do you format a URI for passing in the ingredient parameters?

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing a complex data type, the URL can be formatted this way:

`http://example.com/api/example/getElement?Id={id}&Name={name} &Ingredients[0][Id]={ingredient_id}&Ingredients[0][Name]={ingredient_name}&Ingredients[1][Id]=...`

You need to pass as a two dimensional array of `Ingredients` as you declared it to be an `ICollection<Ingredient>`.